# Solve x^n%k with huge exponents.

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

Hey so I'm trying to provide proof of the answer to :

```
9000008 ^ 625767 % 9
```

I've solved the answer, and I believe a valid way to prove this is via induction, however while I know the inductive proof should be true I cannot figure out a valid way to write this out. I've researched a bunch on this topic and they validate the theory I used, but do not provide a proper way to prove it. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If you solved the modular equation, why not include your solution? And who validates the theory you used?

Comment: Reduce $x$ mod $k$ then repeatedly multiply it by itself (and reduce) until it repeats. Use that information to figure out what it will be after $n$ repetitions.

Comment: [1] For any $a,b,k,n \in \mathbb{Z^+},~$ by binomial expansion you have that $a \equiv b\pmod{n} \implies a^k \equiv b^k \pmod{n}~$. [2] For any  $a,k,r,s,n \in \mathbb{Z^+}, \{a^k \equiv 1\pmod{n} ~\text{and}~ r \equiv s\pmod{k}\} \implies a^r \equiv a^s \pmod{n}.$  These two **tools** resolve the problem completely.

Comment: for $\gcd(k,x)=1$, reduce $n$ modulo $\varphi(k)$.

Comment: Re my previous comment, mathematical induction is **not** a good idea, for this problem.  The direct approach works fine.

Comment: We can't validate anything if you don't show it to us. Even if it's not fully organized, **something** is way better than *nothing*. I doubt this question will be re-opened, but bear it in mind for any future questions you raise. [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We see that $9000008 \equiv (-1)$ modulo $9$, since $9000008 + 1 = 9000009 = 9 \cdot 1000001$. Therefore, we must compute $(-1)^{625767}$, which is $(-1)$ since $625767$ is odd. Finally, $-1 \equiv 8$ modulo 9. So the final answer is 8.